# Why is std::size_t 4 bytes on 32bit systems when unsigned long long is 8 bytes on both 32bit and 64 bit systems?

Tags: c++

Question is quite simple.

On 32bit systems:

```
std::cout << sizeof(unsigned int);        //4
std::cout << sizeof(unsigned long long);  //8
std::cout << sizeof(std::size_t);         //4
```

On 64bit systems:

```
std::cout << sizeof(unsigned int);        //4
std::cout << sizeof(unsigned long long);  //8
std::cout << sizeof(std::size_t);         //8
```

I only checked the implementation that MSVC has, and it looks like this:

```
#ifdef _WIN64
    typedef unsigned __int64 size_t;
#else
    typedef unsigned int     size_t;
#endif
```

So why not make `std::size_t` `unsigned long long` (`std::uintmax_t`) on both 32bit and 64bit systems when they clearly support it? Or am I wrong in that?

Comment: size_t should be the most efficient type that is big enough to hold the size of the biggest possible object.  On a 32 bit system, that is a 32-bit unsigned integer.  64 bit is less efficient on a 32 bit system.  (Even on x86-64, 64 bit is a trivial amount less efficient than 32-bit, but 32-bit isn't big enough for the size of max size objects).  In 32-bit mode, even on a 64-bit CPU, 64-bit unsigned is a lot less efficient than 32-bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The point of `size_t` is to be able to hold the size of the biggest possible object. On a 32 bit system no object can occupy more than 2**32 bytes, so a 32 bit type is sufficient.

To use a 64 bit type would be wasteful of space and potentially more expensive in run time.

Answer (score 6):

That would be a pointless waste. On a 32 bit machine you have a 4 GB address space, so you cannot have objects bigger than 4 GB, so the range of a 32 bit `size_t` is perfectly adequate.